# Как посмотреть свободное место из терминала Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Как посмотреть свободное место из терминала Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

С помощью команды df.

```
alpha@beta:~$ df -h
Файловая система            Разм  Исп  Дост  Исп% смонтирована на
/dev/sda5              20G   13G  6,5G  66% /
none                  493M  324K  493M   1% /dev
none                  498M  400K  497M   1% /dev/shm
none                  498M   88K  498M   1% /var/run
none                  498M     0  498M   0% /var/lock
none                  498M     0  498M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

Comment: а ещё `free -h` есть